# Is there an equivalent to a variablesMap(IValidate) method in Wicket for JSR303 with Spring MVC?

Tags: validation, variables, spring-mvc, message, bean-validation

With Wicket I can add my own variables to feedback messages (via a Map) on validation failures using the variablesMap(IValidate) method in a custom validation class that extends AbstractValidator.

Is there a mechanism to do the same with JSR303 validation on web forms using Spring MVC?

I've written my own validator in JSR303 and I would like to add some extra information to my form feedback messages.

Here's an example: Check that a holiday start and end date do not conflict with a List of existing holidays. So the feedback message in the properties file would be something like, "The date {holidayDate} you entered conflicts with {existingHolidayInSystem}".

Thanks in advance for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 0):

In custom constraint you may try to re-create message inside validator:

```
ctx.disableDefaultConstraintViolation();
ctx.buildConstraintViolationWithTemplate("New message").addConstraintViolation();
```

Comment: Thanks @php-coder I'll give that a try tomorrow and let you know how it goes

Comment: I spent a long time on this today...the code above gives me a message but it's not displaying on my web form (I can see it in my server console trace though).  Also, I'm building the message in the code and I would rather have it in a properties file as I stated above. I found that this site is a good source of information [JBoss Hibernate info](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/validator/4.1/reference/en-US/html/validator-customconstraints.html)

Comment: Did you see error messages with `<form:errors />`? (without `path` attribute?